# jQuery multiple click handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the code below working to handle clicking a `link` from a `list`, showing a screen, and then hiding it when the `.back` button is pressed.

Is there a cleaner way to handle the click function for any `x` number of `list` items?

```
$(".container").on("click", ".dog-btn", function() {
  $(".screen1").css("display","flex")
});
$(".container").on("click", "#back", function() {
  $(".screen1").css("display","none")
});
$(".container").on("click", ".cat-btn", function() {
  $(".screen2").css("display","flex")
});
$(".container").on("click", "#back", function() {
  $(".screen2").css("display","none")
});
$(".container").on("click", ".bird-btn", function() {
  $(".screen3").css("display","flex")
});
$(".container").on("click", "#back", function() {
  $(".screen3").css("display","none")
});
```

Comment: From what I see, you just need one handler for `#back`, which to hide all 3 screens.

Comment: Can you post your html too ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use html5 data attributes to pass screen classes.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="container">
<button class="flex" data-screen="screen1"> DOG</button> 
<a href="void(0)" data-screen="screen1" class="back">Back </a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
//Flex Handler
$(".container").on("click", ".flex", function() {
  $("."+$(this).data("screen")).css("display","flex")
});
//Back Button Handler
$(".container").on("click", ".back", function() {
  $("."+$(this).data("screen")).css("display","none")
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, `data-*` surely helps in this OP case.

Answer (score 0):

You can have benefits of `data-*` attributes of HTML5 as its answered here.

But additionally you can put your custom styles in JSON format in data attributes too. So that you don't need to specify it on every control. That would just go with one click handler as below

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var target=$(this).data('target'),
      css = $(this).data('css');
      $(target).css(css);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-css='{"background":"yellow"}'
data-target="#screen1">
click 1
</button>
<button data-css='{"background":"red"}'
data-target="#screen2">
click 2
</button>

<div id="screen1">
screen1
</div>
<div id="screen2">
screen2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mockup without jQuery, using [event delegation](https://gomakethings.com/why-event-delegation-is-a-better-way-to-listen-for-events-in-vanilla-js/) and ES20xx

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", handleEvents);
document.querySelector("#back").click();

function handleEvents(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  const screenMap = {
    "dog-btn": "screen1",
    "cat-btn": "screen2",
    "bird-btn": "screen3",
  };
  if (origin.id && origin.id === "back") {
    const screens = `.${Object.entries(screenMap).map(([key, value]) => value).join(",.")}`;
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(screens))
      .forEach(screen => screen.style.display = "none");
  }
  
  if (Array.from(origin.classList).filter(v => /\-btn$/i.test(v)).length) {
    return document.querySelector(`.${screenMap[origin.classList]}`)
      .style.display = "flex";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen1">screen 1 DOG</div>
  <div class="screen2">screen 2 CAT</div>
  <div class="screen3">screen 3 BIRD</div>
  <button id="back">#back</button>
  <button class="dog-btn">.dog-btn</button>
  <button class="cat-btn">.cat-btn</button>
  <button class="bird-btn">.bird-btn</button>
</div>
```